# How to increase the size of the points of a xy-plot

Tags: font-size, figure

Could you please help me to increase the point size as well as font size in my plot? Many thanks
Here is my code:

```
library("FSA")
DG4<- read.csv("Farooq1.csv")

DG1 <- ageBias(Dorsal_fin1~Dorsal_fin2,data=DG4,
               nref.lab="Reading 2",ref.lab="Reading 1")

plot(DG1,difference=TRUE,xHist=TRUE,yHist=TRUE,
     col.CIsig="black",show.pts=TRUE)
```

And the current plot [can be viewed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD4jc.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! please provide a reproducible example of your dataset, see this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Comment: Thanks for welcoming. I am working on to learn and then provide the data as reproducible example. Could you please download the data from this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kr7TM_lnGadFuqWJutzBvTJg-8CyrdTP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi,
I used this

plot(DG1,difference=TRUE,xHist=TRUE,yHist=TRUE,
col.CIsig="black", cex.main=1.25, cex.lab=6, cex.axis=0.75, show.pts=TRUE)

But only cex.lab works means the font size of y-axis and x-axis titles change only.

Comment: Here is a reproducible example of the data:

library(FSA)
data(WhitefishLC)
ab1 <- ageBias(scaleC~otolithC,data=WhitefishLC,
nref.lab="Scale Age",ref.lab="Otolith Age")
plot(ab1, difference=TRUE,xHist=TRUE,yHist=TRUE,
col.CIsig="black", cex.main=2, cex.lab=2, cex.axis=0.75, show.pts=TRUE)

Comment: I believe you need to specify point size via `cex=` (note: different than `cex.main` or `cex.lab`)  Does that not work?

Comment: @chemdork123 hi,  only cex.lab works. I also want to increase the font size of shows on y and x axis as scale

Comment: The larger points can obtained by adding the cex.pts= as:library(FSA)
data(WhitefishLC)

ab1 <- ageBias(scaleC~otolithC,data=WhitefishLC,
               nref.lab="Scale Age",ref.lab="Otolith Age")

plot(ab1, xHist=TRUE, yHist=TRUE,
     col.CIsig="black", cex.main=2, cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=1, show.pts=TRUE,
     cex.pts=2)

Comment: But still I couldn't increase the font size, need help